# Airprint quality issue with Adobe AIR

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, ipad, air, airprint

i'm developing an app for iPad with AIR, allowing the user to print a page with some dynamic infos and a picture.

So far it's working, i'm using [vitapoly ANE](https://airextensions.net/shop/extensions/social-by-vitapoly/) but the quality is quite blurred.

I draw the bitmap i send to the ANE with :

```
bmp.drawWithQuality(sheet, null, null, null, null, false, StageQuality.BEST);
```

The picture is quite nice, but text is really different from the PDF template i have.
If i increase the size of the bitmapdata, the iPad crashes (ipad mini retina), i guess it's a memory problem.

I don't know if it's a good idea to make a huge bitmap of the page, but i don't think there's much solutions.

thanks !

Comment: I switched to [Janumedia AirPrintAne](https://github.com/janumedia/AirPrintANE/) and it seems to be better (and it's free), i can increase the size of the bitmapdata without making the app crash. I still think there's a better and cleaner way to do this (with a pdf but i can't figure out how), I'll try to enhance this.